# Two divs next to each other, one moves down when text is in the other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs displayed using `display: inline-block`, in order to have them next to each other. This works when neither of the divs have text in them. However, when I put text in one div, it moves it down dramatically, while the other keeps the same position. This happens regardless of what div I put the text in; if I put it in both, however, only the left div will go down.

Here's a codepen to show what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwEKPp

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

#main_container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0px;
}

#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#title_area {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: rgb(60,105,123);
    font-family: "open sans";
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="logo_title_area">
        <div id="logo">
          test
        </div>
        <div id="title_area">
          test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entering text into the divs labelled `logo` and `title_area` will produce the effect I'm talking about.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I need them to remain side-by-side regardless of their contents. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited the question - added the code snippet into the it.

Comment: I didn't know about that way of doing code snippets... will have to bear it in mind, cheers!

Comment: Yep it's recommend to embed the code sample within the answer if you can, but it's even better to include both inline and pen/fiddle demos, like it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just missing the vertical alignment, the default value is `baseline`.

```
E {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Everything works now, very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#logo, #title-area {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `overflow:auto;` for both of the divs and it worked

```
#logo {
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#title_area {
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: rgb(60,105,123);
    font-family: "open sans";
    font-size: 60px;
}
```